# Rendering an EntityType class in Symfony3

Tags: symfony

New to Symfony, and trying to figure out how form rendering works.

My demo app has a student database (real name and ID fields), and I've figured out how to display the database records as an unordered list:

```
{%block body %}
<ul>
{% for student in students %}
  <li>{{ student.realname }} [{{student.studentid}}]</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

and for my next trick, I'd like to give the app user the ability to delete one or more students from the database.

I used "createFormBuilder" and the "EntityType" class to build that form:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('deleteChoice', EntityType::class,
                    array('class' => 'AppBundle:Student',
                          'choice_label' => 'realname',
                          'multiple' => true,
                          'expanded' => true,
                          'label' => false))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Delete Student'))
            ->getForm();
```

but the default rendering gives me the checkboxes and students in a horizontal line:

```
[] Dave Adams [] Jane Smith [] Todd Burke
[ Delete Student ]
```

The logic works, but the rendering is sub-optimal.

What I'd like is something more like the "show roster" list:

```
[] Dave Adams
[] Jane Smith
[] Todd Burke
[ Delete Student ]
```

but I'm not sure, at all, how to do that.

If I could get a `<div>` ... `</div>` around each pair of fields (the checkbox and the label), I could style it.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Best,
Stephen

Comment: Rendering the form - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-the-form, Rendering a Form in a template - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-rendering-template, How to Customize Form Rendering - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Update: Going with the "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" theme, set in app/config/config.yml, resolved the issue.